# Dynamic resize of Vimeo Video (or Youtube)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I added to to the iframe a class with css

```
width:100%;
height:auto;
```

but does not work for the height.

Any ideas better than jquery dirty fix

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var tempwidth=$(".vimeoiframe").width();
    var tempheight=tempwidth/1.25;
    $(".vimeoiframe").css("height",tempheight);
});
```

Since not all my videos have this aspect ratio.

Comment: Your jQuery dirty fixed worked pretty damn well for me if I may say so. Way better than having to use a plugin to do such a simple thing.

Comment: @lee I also use it rather than plugins when I know all videos will have same aspect ratio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should take a look at this jQuery plugin, seams that was wrote for you

> [FitVids.js](http://fitvidsjs.com/)

There is an entire article about it on [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/) as well

> [Fluid Width YouTube Videos](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-youtube-videos/)

And his [.net magazine](http://www.netmagazine.com) article

> [Create fluid width videos](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/create-fluid-width-videos)

Comment: Thank you very much! The idea with storing the original W/H data is great!

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use percentage ratios, http://codepen.io/maxmckenzie/pen/hFzak the video dose not load in codepen for some reason.